# Link spam and various garbage that I didn't write inside my CSS

Tags: css

I was looking through some CSS and found this huge wall of text with various URLs on the first div within the body of the page (named .bannerAd)

I have no idea what this is or where it came from. What's going on?

[random garbage I found in my CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM3nb.png)

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this CSS file something you created from scratch? are you using en external sheet? do you have scripts on your project? Please provide more details

Comment: no Javascript or script of any kind, yet. I pulled all the HTML from some old websites my grandfather built and started tinkering with them to make them less 1999. All the CSS is written from scratch. 

I'm using normalize.css too, almost forgot. And a google webfont if it matters.

Comment: Do you see this if you inspect the site in the developer tools of the browser  or is it really in your css files. Because it looks like you use an AdBlocker extension in your browser.

Comment: It's in the devtools not in the CSS file. Is this what an adblocker looks like in the devtools? I had no idea.

Comment: @DenW not necessarily, but it seems so. So if you have an AdBlocker installed, then deactivate it and check if those css rules are still there.

Comment: @t.niese Yeah, you hit the nail on the head. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You  may have some malware intercepting your browser traffic. See where it says afu.php?

http://it-help.info/how-to/hijackers/3542-how-to-remove-onclkds-com-afu-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an installed AdBlocker installed that adds additional css rules to hide ads.